# .htaccess Rewrite last five directories as GET values

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

https://sub.example.com/economy/billing/payment-check/434/khipu/1000/CLP/1673526088/

I want the last 5 directories to be converted to GET values, to reflect the following URL:

https://sub.example.com/economy/billing/payment-check/?id=434&gateway=khipu&amt=1000&curr=CLP&ts_ttPageLoad=1673526088

I have the following .htaccess lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?id=$1&gateway=$2&amt=$3&curr=$4&ts_ttPageLoad=$5 [QSA,L]
```

Over at https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ I get the following rewrite result:

https://sub.example.com/index.php?id=economy/billing/payment-check/434&gateway=khipu&amt=1000&curr=CLP&ts_ttPageLoad=1673526088

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

EDIT: The .htaccess is located in https://sub.example.com/economy/billing/payment-check/

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` going to be located? In the document root or in the `/economy/billing/payment-check/` "subdirectory"? And to confirm, the file that actually handles the request in that subdirectory is `index.php`?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, forgot to mention! It's in https://sub.example.com/economy/billing/payment-check/

Answer (score 0):

The regex quantifier `*` is *greedy* by default so consumes as much as possible and then backtracks as required. This is why `$1` contains `economy/billing/payment-check/434` (ie. as much as possible that satisfies the regex). Although, this is assuming the `.htaccess` file is in the document root (which is what the "MWL tester" assumes).

If you are wanting to match a single path segment only then exclude the slash from the capturing subpattern, eg. `([^/]+)`.

Also, from the nature of your rule, I'm assuming this `.htaccess` file is in the `/economy/billing/payment-check/` subdirectory (not the root)? The "MWL tester" tool assumes the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root (and this cannot be changed). In fact, this would "work" on your server if the `.htaccess` file is located in the subdirectory, however, it is not optimal, as it could still potentially match too much given a variation in the URL structure.

If the `.htaccess` file is located at `/economy/billing/payment-check/.htaccess` then use the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?id=$1&gateway=$2&amt=$3&curr=$4&ts_ttPageLoad=$5 [QSA,L]
```

The regex `[^/]+` matches something except a slash.

If, however, the rule is in the root `.htaccess` file (which the MWL tester is expecting) then the rule would need to look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(economy/billing/payment-check)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/index.php?id=$2&gateway=$3&amt=$4&curr=$5&ts_ttPageLoad=$6 [QSA,L]
```

Note that the first capturing subpattern is now the URL-path, that is repeated in the *substitution* string (2nd argument). This simply avoids having to manually repeat the URL-path in the 2nd argument.

It looks like your URL is expecting specific data types in the path segments. For instance, the 1st, 3rd and 5th "parameters" look to be digits only. If this is the case then you should be specific and match digits only. Likewise, the 4th "param" is uppercase and the 2nd is lowercase letters. So, being specific, this could be rewritten like this (with the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory):

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/([A-Z]+)/(\d+)/$ index.php?id=$1&gateway=$2&amt=$3&curr=$4&ts_ttPageLoad=$5 [QSA,L]
```

It then only matches the *format* of URLs you are expecting.